# react handle simultaneous click and blur events

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button with an `onClick` event and an input with an `onBlur` event. I need the onBlur event to fire only after the onClick is done. I can not use setTimeout since the function in onBlur relies upon the state changed by the button press

desired result:

```
<button onClick={//fire first and set state} />
<input onBlur={//fire after and rely on state} />
```

is there a way to make these events fire synchronously?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you're going to have to redesign this. IIRC, if an `input` has focus and the user clicks another `input`, on some browsers the `blur` on the first `input` fires before the `click` on the second, and in some other browsers it's the other way around. So rather than relying on that event sequence, design it so that either sequence works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes... that's what the question is about...

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the question is about. You've said you're relying on a specific order and asking how to do that (as far as I can tell). I'm saying: You probably can't rely on that order, so don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use the setState() call for the button, use it's callback to trigger the blur:

```
...
this.setState({ someButtonState: bool }, () => blurInput());
```

After the button modifies the state then it will call the blurInput() method. In there, do some minor javascript to cause the blur, ie.,

```
blurInput = () => {
  document.getElementById(yourInputButtonId).blur();
}
```

Then should do it, from the text of your question. Should be noted it would be synchronous not asynchronous, if you do it an order.